# SQL splitting a string

Tags: sql-server-2017

From the dept column, I want to create a new column that just returns what is on the right side of the hyphen. It should look like the NewDept column. Thank you

[image: Dept Misc - SiouxFallsES VCD - HuronLS Lit Debtor - SiouxFallsLS]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could fix the table definition (because the current table schema really is _**broken**_ if you need to do this) so data is imported into two separate columns in the first place?

Comment: I updated, but I'm not sure how to make it not a link

Comment: Post what you have tried, post any errors or exceptions you get. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I didn't mean the question... I mean in your actual application. Change the application and database table structure to record two columns in the first place. So instead of `Misc - SiouxFallsES`, you have `Misc` and `SiouxFallsES` in separate fields in the database.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm located not all that far from the Sioux Falls/Huron/Mitchell area.

Comment: `TRIM(SUBSTRING(Dept, CHARINDEX('-', Dept) + 1, LEN(Dept)))`